# How to set version for grails application when deployed

Tags: grails, groovy

insted of using

```
 grails> set-version
```

command, is there any possible ways to generate application version when deployed itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can set it by changing `app.version` in application.properties (at the project base directory).

I'm not completely clear what you mean by "when deployed", but you could change the version programmatically during your build (by editing the file), if that's what you're asking.

Once the application is packaged up into a war and deployed, changing the version would be tougher. You can rename the war (to not include the version), if that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: I think you mean "app.version".  "app.grails.version" indicates the version of Grails, not the app.

Answer (score 2):

The app version is static; the `set-version` script simply updates the version number in `application.properties`. The version is a build-time property, it's not something that you would change at deployment time.

I'm not sure why you would want to change a version number during deployment. From a configuration management perspective build numbers are usually part of the build itself and don't ever change until there is another build.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this (grails 3.3.0) by setting the version parameter in build.gradle file of the application

```
version "0.2"
```